# PresentViewController Troubleshooting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In my swift app I am trying to make it so that a button tap switches view controllers. This is the code I am using:

```
presentViewController(pythTheoremViewController.self, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This returns the error "Cannot invoke 'presentViewController' with an argument list of type')pythTheoremViewController.Type, animated: Bool, completion: nil)

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your ViewController-instance is pythTheoremViewController, remove the self

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question! I used the autocorrect .self option, when I should have used () after the view controller name.